# Piccaso does not show the image loaded in the recycleview

Tags: android

I am doing a small book search program with json and google books api, when I try to use picasso to put the url extracted by json in the `recycleview` it does not work, I would appreciate the help.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Libro libro = list.get(position);


    //Textview
    holder.libropaginas.setText(Integer.toString(libro.getPageCount()));
    holder.fechalibro.setText(libro.getPublishedDate());
    holder.libroautor.setText(libro.getAuthors());
    holder.librotitulo.setText(libro.getTitle());
    holder.libroeditorial.setText(libro.getPublisher());
    /////falta la descripcion


    //ratingbar

    holder.ratinglibro.setRating((int)libro.getAverageRating());

    //imageview

    Picasso.get().load(libro.getImagenportada()).centerInside().resize(125,200).into(holder.imagenlibro);


}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView librotitulo, libroeditorial, libroautor,libropaginas,fechalibro,descripcionlibro;
    public ImageView imagenlibro;
    public RatingBar ratinglibro;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        librotitulo=itemView.findViewById(R.id.titulolibro);
        libroeditorial=itemView.findViewById(R.id.editoriallibro);
        libroautor=itemView.findViewById(R.id.autorlibro);
        libropaginas=itemView.findViewById(R.id.paginalibro);
        fechalibro=itemView.findViewById(R.id.fechalibro);

        imagenlibro=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagenlibro);

        ratinglibro=itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratinglibro);


    }
}
```

Comment: please check this in Logcat---libro.getImagenportada();

Comment: I have used Log.d ("url image:", libro.getImageported ()); and returns the image url correctly

Comment: are you able to open that URL in Browser

Comment: yes, i can open it

Comment: may be us big or view is proper on item view post all code

Comment: I have proven that if I use a url of an image that does not come from the google books API it works perfectly, instead if I use for example this url that comes from the book.getImagenportada () = http://books.google.com/books/content?id=OgdNDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api the image is not shown.

Comment: Do one thing, once put static image from adpater like imageview.setImageresource(R.Drawable.xyz); , if it work then we go further

Comment: You need to debug step by step, it is just a little mistake may be

Comment: I tried what you told me (imageview.setImageresource (R.Drawable.xyz);) and it works correctly

Comment: Now do one thing , take url from google and try to set with picasso, it can be issue of your server can be.

Comment: The only url that don't work for me are those extracted from google books api

Answer (score 0):

i solve it, just adding android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in manifest, looks like, that unprotected traffic is no longer available for making requests to the Google Books servers, thx all for your help